# Embed HTML or Word-formatted text in webpage

Tags: asp.net, html, ms-word

We are currently porting an Intranet-application from ASP to ASP.NET.
The ASP-version uses a lot of frames which I'm trying to avoid in the new version of course.

The application has a Documents-module and I've noticed that the content of some documents are filled with Word-formatted text.
This interferes with the layout of the application. The ASP-version doesn't has this problem because it uses frames and therefore doesn't interfere with the rest of the layout.

The HTML/Word-formatted text is cleaned up with the [Tidy.NET-library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/) which has a property Word2000. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to clean all Word-formatted text.
What are the available options to insert/show Word-formatted text in a webpage? Or is frames the only way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using an `iframe` or use RegEx to strip out the markup that is not getting removed by Tidy.NET library. Here's a tutorial to some RegEx usage in .NET [RegEx tutorial](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/regexlearnsyntax.aspx)

Comment: I considered regular expressions but it's not my cup of tea. I've read and used the article on Coding Horror (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/cleaning-words-nasty-html.html) but unfortunately it's HTML saved by Word and not regular Word. Maybe it's time to learn regular expressions...